# Is it possible to query a category with specified posts?

Tags: posts, wp-query, pages, shortcode, templates

I have a page I'm setting up with various sections to display posts.  I want the majority of the page to be user-editable, so I'm filling the sections using a shortcode I wrote.  Example:

This:

```
[diversecity section="sounds-flavors" ids=""]
```

becomes this:

```
$qs = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'category_name' => 'sounds-flavors'
    )
);
```

and returns 3 posts from the "Sounds & Flavors" category.

However, the users want to be able to highlight certain articles in each section, so I added the `ids` variable in the shortcode.  The idea is that users can put in a comma-separated list of IDs, and that those posts will be prepended to the category list.

This:

```
[diversecity section="sounds-flavors" ids="12345,12678"]
```

becomes this:

```
$qs = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'category_name' => 'sounds-flavors',
        'post__in' => array(12345,12678)
    )
);
```

but only returns the two posts specified.  The desired output is this:

```
<article id="12345">{First ID Specified}</article>
<article id="12678">{Second ID Specified}</article>
<article id="12980">{Most Recent Post from the Sounds & Flavors category}</article>
```

I know I can do two queries (one for the specified posts, and for any category posts to fill the remainder, but is it possible to do it in one using WP_Query?

I'm essentially trying to mimic the behavior of sticky posts, so it should technically be possible.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom select query:

```
$querystr = "
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
WHERE ($wpdb->terms.name = 'sounds-flavors' OR $wpdb->posts.ID IN(12345,12678))
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
LIMIT 3
";
```

Take a look here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query
Regards

Comment: Thank you for weighing in Francisco.  I've been experimenting with a custom query, but I haven't been able to get predictable results, either in the ordering of the articles, or the articles being pulled.